# How do I install Bem++?

Tags: 14.04, python, canopy

I don't have any experience in using Ubuntu but I want to use this software: http://www.bempp.org/ which unfortunately forced me to use Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu and later when I tried to install the software.

```
~/Desktop/bempp$ python bempp_setup.py -b bempp_setup.cfg
```

But I received this error.

```
BEM++ INSTALLATION FAILED WITH ERROR MESSAGE: 
Could not find the Python runtime library in either '/usr/lib' or '/usr/lib64'. Specify its location manually by setting the 'lib' option in the 'Python' section of your configuration file.
```

I would like to get some help in tackling this error. I have installed Enthought Canopy on my system using this guide: http://docs.enthought.com/canopyg /quick-start/install_linux.html but it looks like I need to make some modifications so that the software (BEM++) can find the python runtime library. I am confused and not sure what to do. Please help!

PROGRESS

So turns out I can specify the location of python runtime library in bempp_setup.cfg like this:

```
include_dir=/usr/include/python2.7
lib=/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
```

So this brings me to my next question that how do I find out where these files are on my system?

Comment: What command did you entered to get that error? Please, show us the full output.

Comment: I have added the command in my question.

Comment: why did you not used the command `sudo apt-get install python` or software center to install it? it is easier.

Comment: Upload the content of the file `bempp_setup.cfg` into http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and add it into your question.

Comment: Maybe change the title of your question if you're not asking about installing Python? Python is installed by default in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The application you are trying to build from source and install, includes some non-Python code, and therefore you probably are missing the required dependencies. You will also need the development files for building C/C++ applications that link to the Python runtime or provide compiled modules for it. You can do this by running:

`sudo apt-get install python-all-dev`

You will also need to install the `g++` and `gfortran` compilers, as indicated at http://www.bempp.org/installation.html .

Comment: I have installed both g++ and gfortran. I keep getting the same error!

Comment: Looks like I can manually specify the location of python runtime library. I am gonna edit my question.

Comment: Did you install python-all-dev? g++/gfortran don't include the development files for python, which is what is needed.